# Accessing raspberry pi ports

Tags: java, serial-port, raspberry-pi

Is their a certain way of accessing the raspberry pi ports using java? Such as writing a program in java on the raspberry pi, and running it, and maybe having a java button make a pin in the raspberry pi high or low. Is there a certain library or certain code to access them? Thanks.

Comment: [Seems that way](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=34&t=17992)

Answer (score 5):

You can have a look on the Pi4j project and on this exemple http://pi4j.com/example/control.html

Answer (score 1):

you can use Wiring PI a low level library to manipulate GPIO using command-line
this example can be useful (to use after install Wiring PI):
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo gpio -g mode 18 output");
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("sudo gpio -g write 18 1");

Answer (score 0):

@DrewWood there is a python library called Rpi.GPIO that allows you to accomplish this.  There are two general purpose input/output (GPIO) numbering schemes, BOARD and BCM, once you set the scheme you can write to a pin by setting it to true or false which is the same as hi or low.  You can also set to 1 or 0 which is the same thing.

I use this with a bread board for powering electrical components, like a 7 segment LED, and sensor I/0